# Custom button not responding to mvvmlight Events.TouchUpInside

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvm-light

I've created a number of custom buttons (image on the left of the button, text next to it, aligned vertically). The buttons show fine on the UI, and the code to bind to the mvvmlight VM also works without a problem.

However, when I click a button, nothing happens at all.

The binding looks like this

```
// at class level
private UIButton btnViewReceipts;

// in the create button method
this.btnViewReceipts = UICreation.CreateImageButton(new CGPoint(16, 300), "Images/receipt.png", "View Receipts");

// in the binding method
this.btnViewReceipts.SetCommand(Events.TouchUpInside, this.ViewModel.NavigateToReceiptsCommand);
```

The debugger is not showing anything of issue and the binding is performed before the buttons are added to the view.

Does mvvmlight prohibit binding to custom buttons or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue before in a customized button where I added a UIView to the button and the touch events were not getting to the button. Try setting the user interaction enabled to false or resign to first responder for that view